# Nested for loops break yield RParsing Error with R sample function in rpy2 google collab

Tags: r, rpy2, traceback, parse-error, nested-for-loop

I have been messing around with this for far too many hours and am completely at a loss for what to do now.

I am basing my code off of page 5 of this R paper: cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/adjcurve.pdf

And here is the data I'm using: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_OQogXZv2Lm9gWa1bOyGAX1-KwLAI1BK/view`

I'm trying to balance a subset of 'mydata' such that its distribution matches the reference for each curve I wish to obtain AKA balancing the drill plunge depth, which I've put into 3 groups, against sex and age of the patient.

When I don't have the two "if(length(indx) == 0)) {break}" lines, then the error received is

"""
R[write to console]: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
invalid first argument

Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
invalid first argument
"""

Adding in the line break seems to have fixed this above error. However, now I'm receiving a traceback error specifically on the 'select' lines and I have no idea what to do! Please help :(

```
%%R

mydata$group <- factor(1 + 1*(mydata$Drill.Plunge..mm. > 2) + 1*(mydata$Drill.Plunge..mm. > 4), levels=1:3,labels=c("Plunge <= 2 mm", "Plunge 2 - 4 mm", "Plunge > 4 mm"))

for (j in 1:48) {
  for (k in 1:2) {
    n <- temp[3,j,k] # how many to select
      for (i in 1:2) {
        indx <- which(as.numeric(mydata$group)==i 
                      & mydata$Age..yrs.==j 
                      & mydata$Sex==k)
        if(length(indx) == 0)) {break}
        select[i,j,k] <- list(sample(indx, n, replace=(n > temp[i,j,k])))
      }
      indx <- which(as.numeric(mydata$group)==3
                    & mydata$Age..yrs.==j 
                    & mydata$Sex==k)
      if(length(indx == 0)) {break}
      select[3,j,k] <- list(indx) #keep all the group 3 = high
  }
}
```

And the error I'm receiving is:

```
RParsingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-535-64fe8b32f6f6> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('R', '', '\nmydata$group <- factor(1 + 1*(mydata$Drill.Plunge..mm. > 2) + 1*(mydata$Drill.Plunge..mm. > 4), levels=1:3,labels=c("Plunge <= 2 mm", "Plunge 2 - 4 mm", "Plunge > 4 mm"))\n\nfor (j in 1:48) {\n  for (k in 1:2) {\n    n <- temp[3,j,k] # how many to select\n      for (i in 1:2) {\n        indx <- which(as.numeric(mydata$group)==i \n                      & mydata$Age..yrs.==j \n                      & mydata$Sex==k)\n        if(length(indx) == 0)) {break}\n        select[i,j,k] <- list(sample(indx, n, replace=(n > temp[i,j,k])))\n      }\n      indx <- which(as.numeric(mydata$group)==3\n                    & mydata$Age..yrs.==j \n                    & mydata$Sex==k)\n      if(length(indx == 0)) {break}\n      select[3,j,k] <- list(indx) #keep all the group 3 = high\n  }\n}\n\n# data2 <- mydata[unlist(select),]\n\n#sfit2 <- survfit(Surv(Patient.LOS..days., Events) ~ group, data2)\n\n#plot(sfit2, col=c(1,2,4), lty=1, lwd=2, xlab="Days", ylab="Patients in ICU (1.0) or released (0.0)")\n\n#lines(sfit1, col=c(1,2,4), lty=2, lwd=1)\n\n#legend(730, .4, levels(mydata$group), lty=1, col=c(1,2,4),bty=\'n\', lwd=2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! This is so simple and I don't understand WHY this is the case. But my so-called fix, is fixing one problem but causing another. So if I simply change it from...

`if(length(indx) == 0)) {break}`  to  `if(length(indx) < 1)) {break}`

...then it works!